# Draw circle with turtle module

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

When I set my world coordinates to (-2,-2,2,2) and attempt to draw a circle using the circle function with radius 1, the figure drawn is a 12 sided polygon instead of a circle. How do I make it a circle?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a [mcve], which can be tested by others. Also add the program/language/engine you use for the turtle graphic.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't supply an explicit `steps` argument, the turtle `circle()` method attempts to calculate an optimal one for you based on the `radius` argument.  That calculation is roughly:

```
steps = 1 + min(11 + abs(radius)//6, 59)
```

Which means `steps` ranges from 12 minimum to 60 maximum.  But the `circle()` method doesn't adjust for `setworldcoordinates()` so your radius of 1 got you the minimum steps of 12.  A simple fix is to supply the `steps` argument explicitly:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(500, 500)  # force a square window
screen.setworldcoordinates(-2, -2, 2, 2)

turtle = Turtle()

turtle.penup()
turtle.sety(-1)  # center the circle
turtle.pendown()

turtle.circle(1, steps=60)

screen.exitonclick()
```